# How to get String replace-method to recognize for example that R35 is not R3

Tags: java

I have string called `formula` which has a ton of R letters followed by digit(s). A snippet of it looks like "R3+R5+R9+R12+R27+R35"
etc. and I have strings to replace each of those R[digit] parts of the string.

My logic has a String reserved for each of those. Let's say there's key R3 with the value "ABC" and my code replaces every "R3" on the huge string with the value "ABC".

As follows `formula = formula.replace(rCode, replacingString);`

Now, the problem is that for example "R35" also contains R3, so when the replace method finds "R3" it correctly replaces it with the string but unfortunately when it finds for example "R35" it ALSO replaces that "R3" part of "R35". Even though a different String value is reserved for R35.

I'd like my replace method to recognize that forexample R35 is not R3 and R27 is not R2 etc. Is there a regex or another way to achieve this?

I was thinking of a way to see if the following character of, for example, R3 is a digit, as is the case in for example R35, and if it is then we're not replacing THAT R3 with the string value in question.

Comment: `R3\\b` - i.e. “R3” followed by a word boundary.

Comment: @BoristheSpider thanks, this did the trick. You can add it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a regex replacement on `\bR3\b`:

```java
String input = "R3 R35";
String output = input.replaceAll("\\bR3\\b", "ABC");
System.out.println(output);  // ABC R35
```

Comment: Anyway to make it more general? To separate R[single digit] and R[multiple digits] before matching and replacing?
Not just R3 but with any similar case. R1 R132, R2 R24, etc.

Comment: Edit the question and reveal the actual problem.

Comment: I edited the question. I hope I make some sense now :D sorry for that.